Estimate the value of the PDF $P(f)$ at the minimal $f_0$ of the random-variable function $f(\mathbf{x})$
Let $f(\mathbf{x})=f(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_N)$ with $N>2$ be a real and continuous function and $f(\mathbf{x})\ge f_0$ for any $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^N$. Now let $x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_N$ be the i.i.d. random variables drawn from the normal distribution. I want to estimate the value of the probability density function $P(f)$ at $f_0$, or specifically, I want to know whethere $P(f_0)$ is zero, finite or divergent. The definition of $P(f_0)$ is
$$
P(f_0)=\int\delta(f(\mathbf{x})-f_0)\rho(\mathbf{x})dx_1\dotsm dx_N,
$$
where $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ is the $N$-dimensional Gaussian distribution. Let us consider a concrete example. The function $f$ is given by
$$
f^{(n)}(\mathbf{x})=-\sum_{m=n+1}^{N}x^2_m+\left(\sum_{m=n+1}^{N}x^2_m\right)^2+\sum_{m=1}^{n}x^2_m.
$$
The minimal value is $f_0=-1/4$, which is taken as long as the condition
$$
\sum_{m=n+1}^{N}x^2_m=\frac{1}{2},\ x_{1}=x_{2}=\dotsb
x_n=0$$
is satisfied. The analytical expression can be obtained by calculating $P(f)$ and letting $f\to f_0$. For $f-f_0\ll1$, the analytical expression of $P(f)$ can be approximately obtained by transforming $(x_1,\dotsc,x_{N-n})$ into the $N-n-1$ sphere and transforming $(x_{N-n+1},\dotsc,x_{N})$ into the $n-1$ sphere coordinates. After some calculations, I found that
$$
\begin{cases}
P(f_0)\to \infty, & n=0, \\
P(f_0)\to \text{constant}, & n=1, \\
P(f_0)\to 0, & n>1.
\end{cases}
$$
That is, whether $P(f_0)$ is zero, finite or divergent seems to depend on the dimension of the solution that satisfies $f(\mathbf{x})=f_0$. If the dimension of solution set is $N-1$, $P(f_0)$ is divergent; if the dimension of solution set is $N-2$ then $P(f_0)$ is finite; otherwise $P(f_0)$ is zero.
Q: For a generic continuous function $f$ as we specified in the begining, does the relation between the dimension of solution set and the behavior of $P(f_0)$ still hold?
